# Test jasmin angular @ViewChild

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have the following component

```
<app-modal-default #confirmDelete>
<span class="title">Delete Confirmation</span>
<span class="modal-body-content">Do you want to delete all the data related to shipping, distribution and storage?
</span>
<div class="modal-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="confirmDeleteOk()">Delete</button>&nbsp;
    <button class="btn-default btn" (click)="close(confirmDelete)">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>
```

I have a view child declared in .ts file

```
@ViewChild('confirmDelete') confirmDelete: ModalDefaultComponent;
```

This view child iam closing in this function

```
confirmDeleteOk(): void {
 this.hTstore$.dispatch(new fromHTAction.DeleteWMS());
 this.close(this.confirmDelete);
}
```

This is my test file

```
it('Calling WMS delete through dispatch Action Should work as expected', fakeAsync((done) => {
 component.confirmDeleteOk();
 storeSpy.dispatch(new DeleteWMS());
 expect(storeSpy.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new DeleteWMS()); }));
```

[iam getting an test error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES5RL.png)

TypeError: element.close is not a function

how to write test for view child for my element.close , how i can define element ?

Comment: Do you have `app-modal-default` added to `declarations` array?

Comment: No, How can i do that this is my spec file before each

`code`
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DeleteDataComponent],
      imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot({})],
      providers: [ToastrService,
        provideMockStore({
          selectors: [
            { selector: selectWMSDeleterror, value: null },
            { selector: selectWMSDeleteCompleted, value: null }
          ],
        })
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

Comment: In the `declarations` array, add `ModalComponent` or whatever the class name is.